# How do i debug a scrapy login form request

Tags: python, authentication, scrapy

I'm trying to login to a web page using scrapy. However it does not seem to work, however I'm am unable to propely debug it because i cant see what is happening throught scrapy. This is the code i got so far:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class WordGetterSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "word_getter"
    #allowed_domains = ["germanpod101.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.example.com/member/login_new.php',
    )

    def parse(self, response):        
      return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'amember_login': 'my username', 'amember_password': 'my password'}, callback=self.parse_index)

    def parse_index(self, response):
      print response.body
      print response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
```

The printed body contains the login form and it is apparent that i am not loged in. If i try to visit other pages that requires login i am redirected back to the login page.

Does anybody have any good tips on how i can debug this or how i can make the login work?

I have added this to my settings as well:

```
COOKIES_ENABLED = True
COOKIES_DEBUG = True
```

Comment: Debug the login process using tools such as the debugger in your browser or/and packet inspectors. Once you know how the login process really works, you should be able to implement in scrapy

Comment: It's possible you may need to send additional headers or you may have missed some required `formdata` fields. Try copying exactly what is sent by a normal browser to your code.

Comment: I suggest you use [`scrapy shell`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html) to try different requests and parameters. As @marven suggest, check your browser's dev tools "network" tab to check what is actually sent, and replicate this in `formdata` (sometimes, field values are added by Javascript)